# Cannot find why value doesn't jump to expectation in the right time

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I have the following code :

```
module POLY(CLK,RESET_n,IN_VALID,IN,OUT_VALID,OUT);

input         CLK,RESET_n,IN_VALID;
input  [ 3:0] IN;
output        OUT_VALID;
output [12:0] OUT;

reg        OUT_VALID;
reg [12:0] OUT;

reg        OUT_VALID_w;
reg [12:0] OUT_w;

reg [ 1:0] COUNT_IN, COUNT_IN_w;
reg [ 2:0] COUNT_DO, COUNT_DO_w;

always @(posedge CLK or negedge RESET_n)
begin
    if(!RESET_n)
    begin
        COUNT_IN <= 2'd0;
        COUNT_DO <= 3'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
        COUNT_IN <= COUNT_IN_w;
        COUNT_DO <= COUNT_DO_w;
    end
end

always @(*)
begin
    if(IN_VALID == 1'b0)
    begin
        if(COUNT_DO == 3'd7)
        begin
            COUNT_DO_w = COUNT_DO;
        end
        else
        begin
            COUNT_DO_w = COUNT_DO + 1'b1;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        COUNT_DO_w = 3'd0;
    end
end
```

Why `COUNT_DO` doesn't jump to 1 in `14ns`?

I think that due to the sensitivity list in the second `always` block is `COUNT_DO` and `IN_VALID`,
so at start, the reset signal trigger first always block and set the `COUNT_DO = 0`, which change the `COUNT_DO` value from high impedance to 0. So, it triggers the second always block `COUNT_DO_w = 0 + 1 = 1`. And , in the next postive edge clock, which trigger the first always block to do `COUNT_DO <= COUNT_DO_w`. But it seems to delay one clock to assign it (`22ns`). Why does it delay one clock?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At time=14ns, reset is asserted (`RESET_N`=0), which means `COUNT_DO`=0 in the 1st always block.  At time t=20ns, you release reset and `COUNT_DO` remains at 0.  At time=22ns, you have your 1st posedge `CLK` which assigns `COUNT_DO` to `COUNT_DO_w`.  The time at which  `COUNT_DO` changes is controlled only by the 1st always block, not the 2nd.

Comment: but doesn't the negedge RESET_n is in 10 ns, and immediately trigger first block?

Comment: and the sensitive list in second block is the righthand side which are  
IN_VALID and COUNT_DO?

Comment: my concept isn't very clear, so if I am wrong please correct me. Thx

Comment: and I think that because `COUNT_DO` has changed, it immediately trigger the second blocks, and executeCOUNT_DO_w = COUNT_DO + 1'b1;

Comment: and the next posedge CLK in 14 ns will execute COUNT_DO <= COUNT_DO_w;
but it do it in 22ns?

Comment: The chip is still in reset at t=14ns, so nothing happens on the positive edge of the clock, because on clock posedge the `if(!RESET_n)` is still true. @Liang-YuPan